# setup akamai local test environment with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, akamai

Maybe someone has already dealt with the task of preparing docker-compose for local development? For starters, I want start with netstorage.

Comment: This is very vague. What, precisely, are you asking for help on? There is plenty of documentation on using Docker with supported products at https://techdocs.akamai.com